# Text in JLabel is displayed layered

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

In a bigger project I need to display single words in a JLabel filling the entire screen. I noticed that words starting with upper case 'W' are displayed layered when using large font sizes (362 and more):

Layered 'What?' size 362:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1Ajy.png]

Normal 'What?' size 361:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxgxE.png]

I tested different starting letters and words, only starting letter 'W' seems to cause it. In addition I tested it both on Windows 10 and Linux and different screen resolutions, only the font size switching between layered and normal text seems to change.
The following code is the minimal example producing the 'strange' behavior:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    label.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    label.setText("What?");
    Font old = label.getFont();
    panel.add(label);
    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    //label.setFont(new Font(old.getFontName(), Font.BOLD, 361)); // normal (WIN10)
    label.setFont(new Font(old.getFontName(), Font.BOLD, 362)); // layered (WIN10)
}
```

Can someone explain that behavior or is it simply a bug?

Edit:

I further experimented with it, I could not find any other letter causing this and length of the word does not seem to matter (not even if the text is abbreviated).
I checked several different fonts (e.g. Arial, Caladea, Consolas, Noto Serif, Segoe Print, ...), all seem to be affected with different font sizes. All styles (plain, bold and italic) are affected. If i calculate the width of the 'W' (with TextLayout.getBounds()), it seems like widths <~340 result in the normal presentation and widths >~340 result in layered one.
Repaint, revalidate, invalidate didn't change anything.
I tested it on all my machines (Win10, Linux Mint) with different screen resolutions. (It only worked normally on a device with activated Windows screen scaling)

Comment: I tried it on OSX and it works as expected. I tried it on linux over x11 forwarding and it also worked fine. Maybe you need to include the Font you're using. It sounds like a bug.